# Email Notification on adding reviewer on gerrit

Tags: gerrit, devops

I want an email notification to get triggered to the reviewer when i will add him on Gerrit?
The current documentation doesn't support it or mention it any where https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html
i am using gerrit 2.11.5 V.
If any one has done it kindly share your experience

Thanks

Comment: in my case it is working now. what i was missing was is --the reviewer should enable that project in settings->watched projects, then only on adding reviewer a mail will get triggered to him.

Answer (score 2):

in my case it is working now. what i was missing was  --the reviewer should enable that project in settings->watched projects, then only on adding reviewer a mail will get triggered to him.

Before that make sure that you have followed the following link https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-notify.html